# attr('class') and hasClass() giving conflicting results

Tags: jquery

I'm getting some confusing results in jQuery, with attr('class') and hasClass(). Basically, I am traversing through table rows and figuring out if the next visible table row has a certain class.

```
$('table#blocks tr.region').each(function () {
    var next_row = $(this).nextAll('tr:visible');
            
    console.log('This: ' + $(this).attr('class') + ' Next: ' + next_row.attr('class') + ' Next is a region: ' + next_row.hasClass('region'));
                     
 });
```

When I run this script, the log shows:

> This: region region-left Next: region region-right Next is a region: true
>
> This: region region-right Next: region region-content Next is a region: true
>
> This: region region-content Next: **draggable even shown_on_home shown_on_infozone** Next is a region: **true**
>
> This: region region-header Next: **region-message region-header-message region-empty** Next is a region: **true**
>
> This: region region-footer Next: **region-message region-footer-message region-empty** Next is a region: **true**
>
> This: region region--1 Next: undefined Next is a region: false

So the message clearly shows that some rows have the class 'region' and some don't, but they all return true for hasClass()!

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Any progress on this Maria? Why don't you provide feedback on the answers given? Does my answer not work for your?

Answer (score 1):

The error comes partially from your use of `nextAll()` which "*Finds all sibling elements after the current element*". Thus you always select all visible rows which follow the current one.

The discrepancy between the value returned from `attr()` and `hasClass()` can be explained if you reread the documentation about them

> **attr( name )**
>
> Access a property on the
>   first matched element.

vs.

> **hasClass( class )**
>
> Returns true if the specified class is
>   present on at least one of the set of
>   matched elements.

This explains it all. You use `nextAll` which selects multiple siblings, `attr` only show the `class` attribute of the first element matched, while `hasClass` returns true if one of all the elements matched has the class.

My advice is to use `var next_row = $(this).next('tr:visible');`. Which will only give you the next visible sibling row.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer! When I console.log'd the result of:

```
var next_row = $(this).nextAll('tr:visible');
```

it stated that next_row was a [Object object], when it was actually an array of objects. I found this out using debugger;. So i just needed to change the line to:

```
var next_row = $(this).nextAll('tr:visible:first');
```

and now it works.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you using `nextAll()` anyway? If you only want the first row, you should use `next()` like the other answer suggests...

Answer (score 0):

First of you should never declare "var" in a iterator. Always declare it outside.

Your .hasClass('region') will always return true since your next_row return all tr elements. Use .next('tr:visible') instead.

The reason you get different classes with .attr() is that it returns the first element of your selector.

..fredrik